# QT 5 C++ как обратиться к двум БД

Tags: c++, mysql, sqlite, qt5, qsqldatabase

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему, долго мучался, но так ничего и выходит. Нужно работать одновременно с двумя типами БД как это можно реализовать? По отдельности всё работает, а вместе не хочет. В консоли выводит:

```
("QSQLITE", "QMYSQL3", "QMYSQL") 
("QSQLITE", "QMYSQL3", "QMYSQL") 
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
false 
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
bad
```

Поиск нужных результатов не дал, нашёл это:

> QSqlDatabase defaultDB = QSqlDatabase::database(); QSqlDatabase
> firstDB = QSqlDatabase::database("first"); QSqlDatabase secondDB =
> QSqlDatabase::database("second");

Но как применить к проекту не пойму. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
// mysql_connect.h
#ifndef MYSQL_CONNECT
#define MYSQL_CONNECT

#endif // MYSQL_CONNECT

static bool createConnection()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "dbsql");
    db.setDatabaseName("job_db");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setPassword("pass");
    qDebug() << db.drivers();
    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug() << "Cannot open database: " << db.lastError();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
static bool createConnectionMYSQLite(QString path)
{
    QSqlDatabase dbsqlite = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "dbsqlite");
    dbsqlite.setDatabaseName(path);
    qDebug() << dbsqlite.drivers();
    if (!dbsqlite.open()) {
        qDebug() << "Cannot open database: " << dbsqlite.lastError();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


// extract_mail.cpp
    QString create_sql_add (QString sql_add);
    QString create_sql_add_2 (QString name, QString value);
    void extract_mail_is_file (QString files);
    QString extract_is_thunderbird (QString path);
    
void extract_mail ()
{
    createConnection();    
    QString files; 
    files = "global-messages-db.sqlite";
    extract_is_thunderbird (files);    
}
QString extract_is_thunderbird (QString path)
{
    createConnectionMYSQLite (path);
    QSqlQuery query;
    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
    QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(codec);
    QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(codec);
    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(codec);

    qDebug() << (query.exec("SELECT name, value FROM contacts, identities WHERE contacts.id = identities.contactID;"));

    // Считываем данные из базы
    QSqlRecord rec  = query.record();
    int     nNumber = 0;
    QString strName, buf;
    QString strValue;
    buf = create_sql_add_2("strName", "strValue");
    cout << buf.toStdString() << endl;
    while (query.next()){
        strName  = query.value(rec.indexOf("name")).toString();
        strValue = query.value(rec.indexOf("value")).toString();
        if (strName != strValue)
        {
            create_sql_add_2(strName, strValue);

        } else {
            strName = "";
            create_sql_add_2(strName, strValue);
            }    
    }    
}

QString create_sql_add_2 (QString name, QString value)
{   // создадим запрос SQL для добавления адреса в БД
    QString x;
    QSqlQuery query;
    x = "INSERT INTO addressbook (name, email) "
              "VALUES ('";
    x += name; x += "', '"; x += value;
    x += "');";
    if (query.exec(x)){cout << "OK" << endl;} else {cout << "bad" << endl;}
    return x;
}
```

Comment: А чего это базы в локальных переменных?

Comment: если используется только одна база, то проблем нет всё работает. делал так как видел варианты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на [конструкторы](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html) `QSqlQuery`:

```
QSqlQuery(QSqlResult *result)
QSqlQuery(const QString &query = QString(), QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase())
QSqlQuery(QSqlDatabase db)
QSqlQuery(const QSqlQuery &other)
```

В вашем случае: делая так - `QSqlQuery query;` - вы вызываете второй из списка конструктор с параметрами по умолчанию, а вам нужно при создании каждого объекта `QSqlQuery` указать с каким подключением он будет работать (т.е. вызвать третий конструктор):

```
QSqlQuery query_sqlite(QSqlDatabase::database("dbsqlite"));
QSqlQuery query_mysql(QSqlDatabase::database("dbsql"));
```

Comment: Благодарю. Я в общем и предполагал нечто подобное, но как реализовать не находил.